# Canvas automatically resizes to 50x50

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I'm trying to transfer a fairly big project from Khan Academy to the "real" world, but keep getting the same problem, when I run my code the canvas resizes to a lot smaller than I wanted and turns grey.

I've tried reducing the code to a minimum but the problem persists.

The console shows a few errors in Chrome, but nothing unexpected in Firefox. Problem is the same in both browsers though.

Html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/processing-js/processing- 
js/v1.4.8/processing.js"></script>        
<canvas id="NNcanvas" width="600" height="600" data-processing- 
sources="EllipseTest.js" style="border:1px solid #000000";></canvas>
```

JavaScript:

`ellipse(50,50,100,50);`

Comment: Please provide us with more code. The current code can't be used to recreate your issue.

Comment: The code above is all that I use after scaling away as much as possible to find out where the problem is. Tried it on Edge as well now, then the canvas keeps its size, but no ellipse is drawn. Running it on /localhost using MAMP if that somehow could matter, and running Firefox in safemode.

Comment: Can you please post a CodePen or JSFiddle showing your code as a [mcve]? Can you please post the errors you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing a CodePen or JSFiddle that shows a working version of your code this it's hard to say for sure, but my best guess is that you need a call to the `size()` function. Try a more complete program:

```
void setup(){
  size(600, 600);
}

void draw(){
  ellipse(50, 50, 100, 50);
}
```

Keep in mind that Khan Academy is not an exact 1:1 copy of Processing.js. Khan Academy's version does a few things for you behind the scenes, and I'm guessing that sizing the canvas is one of them. In "real" Processing.js, you have to do that yourself by calling the `size()` function. There are other differences, such as using degrees instead of radians, that you'll have to look out for.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js) is a guide on using Processing.js.

Comment: That works, just needed to add type="application/processing" to the script tag to get rid of the last bug. Is there any reason to specify canvas size in the html file?

Comment: @Bjathr Honestly I'm not sure. I think Processing is going to overwrite any sizes you set anyway.